# Emails being spoofed? Constantly blacklisted

Tags: email, postfix, centos-6, dkim, spf

Please point me in the right direction if this isn't the best place to ask this but I manage a linux based (centos) server using Plesk.

We were subject to a spam attack a couple of months ago where over 360,000 emails were sent (apparently from us) and we had thousands of bounced emails in our inboxes.

I already have SPF, DKIM, DMARC set up and can't seem to find where I'm going wrong.

We've just been subject to another attack and its not going to be long now until we're AGAIN on every blacklist possible (making it impossible for us to contact any of our actual customers).

Our SPF looks like this;

```
v=spf1 mx include:spf.mandrillapp.com include:_spf.google.com -all
```

Our maillog has been filled with thousands of these;

```
Nov 20 21:32:41 hostname postfix/smtpd[45682]: warning: unknown[221.155.161.131]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Nov 20 21:32:41 hostname postfix/smtpd[45682]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[221.155.161.131]
Nov 20 21:32:41 hostname postfix/smtpd[45682]: disconnect from unknown[221.155.161.131]
Nov 20 21:32:42 hostname postfix/smtpd[45682]: connect from unknown[221.155.161.131]
Nov 20 21:32:44 hostname plesk_saslauthd[45688]: Invalid mail address 'andy@'
Nov 20 21:32:44 hostname postfix/smtpd[45682]: warning: unknown[221.155.161.131]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Nov 20 21:32:44 hostname postfix/smtpd[45682]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[221.155.161.131]
Nov 20 21:32:44 hostname postfix/smtpd[45682]: disconnect from unknown[221.155.161.131]
Nov 20 21:32:44 hostname postfix/smtpd[45682]: connect from unknown[221.155.161.131]
Nov 20 21:32:45 hostname plesk_saslauthd[45688]: Invalid mail address 'angel@'
```

And then....

```
Nov 21 09:29:56 hostname postfix/smtpd[47398]: warning: 86-45-150-251-dynamic.agg7.rlc.lmk-mlw.eircom.net[86.45.150.251]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Nov 21 09:29:56 hostname postfix/smtpd[47398]: lost connection after AUTH from 86-45-150-251-dynamic.agg7.rlc.lmk-mlw.eircom.net[86.45.150.251]
Nov 21 09:29:56 hostname postfix/smtpd[47398]: disconnect from 86-45-150-251-dynamic.agg7.rlc.lmk-mlw.eircom.net[86.45.150.251]
Nov 21 09:29:56 hostname postfix/smtpd[47398]: connect from 86-45-150-251-dynamic.agg7.rlc.lmk-mlw.eircom.net[86.45.150.251]
Nov 21 09:29:58 hostname plesk_saslauthd[48264]: Invalid mail address 'temp@'
```

Then shortly after there is over 85MB of maillog data full of sent emails, followed by deferred and blocked emails (due to blacklists).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check whenever your server allows to relay mails for other domains. Look at the mails that were sent through your server to get a feeling for what might be wrong. Do they have a origin of your company or different companies? Is there a pattern to the sender names?

Comment: That's the odd thing, relay is enabled but SMTP authentication is required - the only pattern I've noticed with the emails are they are primarily going to russian/german advertising a russian website.

Comment: Is there a good reason the relay is enabled and not locked down to certain hosts? If you are receiving those mails from authorized hosts talk to the one running that host?